# File & Folders Label tool in For Windows

Tags: windows-7, file-management

I'm looking for tool that allows me to mark folders & Files in Windows ..

I found this app but it's buggy and not working on Windows 7 64x.

> http://eng.softq.org/badges.htm

Please is there any replacement Works with Windows 7 x64?

Comment: I tried gummed labels, but they left the screen kind of sticky.

Comment: Have a look at Folder Marker..http://www.foldermarker.com/